# Click handler for div doesn't work for JQuery full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my `handler`:

```
$("div.fc-content").on('click', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/VacationRequest/Edit/' + id,
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#edit-id").val(data.Id);
            $("#startDate-edit").val(data.startDate);
            $("#endDate-edit").val(data.endDate);
            $("#comment-edit").val(data.comment);
            $("#vacationTypes-edit").val(data.vacationType);
            $('#edit-vacation-modal-window').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

And this is a part of `Jquery` full calendar initialization:

```
function InitCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: '/vacation/SchedulesGet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                title: 'title',                      
                id : 'id',
                start: new Date('start'),
                end: new Date('end'),
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',
            textColor: 'black'
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            $($(element[0]).find('div.fc-content')[0]).attr('data-id', event.id);
        },
```

This `$("div.fc-content")` block is exist (I found it in js console). But When I'm trying to click on it happens nothing. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delegated event handler, like so:

```
$('#calendar').on('click', 'div.fc-content', function (e) {

    ...

});
```

More info on event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Or bind your `onclick` inside the `eventRender` function:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventRender: function (event, element) {

        element.click(function() {
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's work! But can you explain me: why? I don't understand(

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically using a delegated event handler allows you to handle events for DOM elements that are created *after* you actually bound the handler.

Comment: Ok. As I understand, it was necessary to put handlers after calendar loaded. This was a problem. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, after calendar creates its inner elements.